# (node:31260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, async-await

In function called "readPlcDataWriteToDB" i need to wait for data come before return a response. How can i do it ?

i am getting an error in this code about this problem. When i add "await" like "newData = await data;" it is same result no effects.

Please help me for solve this. Tnx..

```js
const asyncErrorWrapper = require("express-async-handler");
var nodes7 = require('nodes7');  // This is the package name, if the repository is cloned you may need to require 'nodeS7' with uppercase S
var conn = new nodes7;
const MachineState = require("../models/MachineState");


var newData;

var doneReading = false;
var doneWriting = false;

var variables = { 

    nMachine1   : 'DB7,BYTE0',
    nMachine2   : 'DB7,BYTE1',
    nMachine3   : 'DB7,BYTE2',
    nMachine4   : 'DB7,BYTE3',
    nMachine5   : 'DB7,BYTE4',
    nMachine6   : 'DB7,BYTE5',
    nMachine7   : 'DB7,BYTE6',
    nMachine8   : 'DB7,BYTE7',
    nMachine9   : 'DB7,BYTE8',
    nMachine10   : 'DB7,BYTE9',
    nMachine11   : 'DB7,BYTE10',
    nMachine12   : 'DB7,BYTE11',
    nMachine13   : 'DB7,BYTE12',
    nMachine14   : 'DB7,BYTE13',
    nMachine15   : 'DB7,BYTE14'
};

  var data;

  conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '192.168.200.1', rack: 0, slot: 1}, connected); // slot 2 for 300/400, slot 1 for 1200/1500

  function connected(err) {
    if (typeof(err) !== "undefined") {
      // We have an error.  Maybe the PLC is not reachable.
      console.log(err);
      process.exit();
    }

    conn.setTranslationCB(function(tag) {return variables[tag];});  // This sets the "translation" to allow us to work with object names
    conn.addItems(['nMachine1' , 'nMachine2' , 'nMachine3' , 'nMachine4' , 'nMachine5' , 'nMachine6' , 'nMachine7' , 'nMachine8' , 'nMachine9' , 'nMachine10' , 'nMachine11' , 'nMachine12' , 'nMachine13' , 'nMachine14' , 'nMachine15']);     
    
  }

  function valuesReady(anythingBad, values) {
    if (anythingBad) { console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG READING VALUES!!!!"); }
    //console.log(values);
    console.log("Done reading.");  
    doneReading = true;



    if (doneWriting) { process.exit(); }
    data = values;
   
    sendDataToDB(values);
    
  }

const readPlcDataWriteToDB = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req,res,next) => { 

    await conn.readAllItems(valuesReady);
    newData = data;
         

    return res
    .status(200)
    .json({
      success :   true,
      data    :   newData
    });
    


    

});



const sendDataToDB = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req,res,next) => {

    let allMachineStates = await MachineState.findOne();
    allMachineStates.Machine.M1 = newData.nMachine1;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M2 = newData.nMachine2;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M3 = newData.nMachine3;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M4 = newData.nMachine4;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M5 = newData.nMachine5;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M6 = newData.nMachine6;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M7 = newData.nMachine7;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M8 = newData.nMachine8;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M9 = newData.nMachine9;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M10 = newData.nMachine10;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M11 = newData.nMachine11;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M12 = newData.nMachine12;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M13 = newData.nMachine13;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M14 = newData.nMachine14;
    allMachineStates.Machine.M15 = newData.nMachine15;
    await allMachineStates.save();
    console.log("PLC'den Alınan Verilere Göre Database Güncellendi");
        
});
 


module.exports = {
    readPlcDataWriteToDB
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDiQo.png)

Comment: The warning is likely unrelated to the failure

Comment: It appears that the error is on the `allMachineStates.Machine.M1 = newData.nMachine1` line, indicating that newData does not have the structure expected

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for nodes7, it appears that readAllItems does not return a Promise, but rather expects a callback. This means that `await` will not correctly wait for it, so the assignment to newData wouldn't work.

Either move the handling of newData to a callback, or try something like [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert the library function to use Promises

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you should put your await calls inside a try-catch structure. Like this:

```
try {
  await myFunctionOne();
  cons myConstOne = await myFunctionTwo();
  .... whatever you need to put here ...
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

From there you would get rid of the "Unhandled-Promise-Rejection" issue and you could see what is causing the problem.

Beside that, you may find useful these few [tutorials about Async-Await](https://tutorama.info/CTG/Async-Await), I myself learned from them and still sometimes refer to them.